# Access wordpress admin area without login

Tags: wordpress, opencart

Currently I am developing a site in Opencart. For the blog, I am using Wordpress but my client does not want two different login sections for opencart and wordpress. Is it possible to redirect a user from the admin of wordpress to OpenCart and vice versa using a link without them having to enter a password each time?
Please advise. Your valuable suggestion will help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by adding a simple plugin, which defines the needed (pluggable) login functions.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions

Basically, rather than logging into WP directly, you'd write the pluggable functions that authenticates the user using OpenCart's details. (Note that hooks allow you to make the login form redirect straight to the latter, too.)

Look for an existing plugin or module that does this. It would be surprising if none exist already.